# Design Patterns for programming

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

I am trying to find the best approach to learning proper Software Engineering design and would appreciate any help in directing me to a foolproof approach to dissect a project prior to its design, and figure out what the most useful design pattern should be implemented. I have read through the "Gang Of Four" yet feel it's missing a surefire way of choosing the proper design pattern to a given software.

I'm not sure how professionals approach this, yet am sure this comes through years of experience. Yet after all my years of programming, am yet to find a process of discovery for design patterns.

Thanks,
Al

Comment: Check this youtuber he is making a playlist about design patterns. And has a very clear explenation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9ejT8FO-7I&list=PLrhzvIcii6GNjpARdnO4ueTUAVR9eMBpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a challenge to choose and apply the correct design pattern for the correct scenario at the correct time. Though the design patterns are supposed to be learned as theories, what makes the flavor for that is someone's ability to identify the time and place where the correct tech decision to be made.

For a learner, my suggestion is to know about as much as patterns and the concepts behind them; and keep them refreshed via given, understandable examples. Then, during your requirement clarification or feature design phase (Grooming/Planning sessions if its on Agile), or development phase (Agile : in the Sprint), or during code reviewing phase try to look at the coding design and brainstorm to find any matching mappings of the patterns that you have known. By practice and experience this skill will be improved and later it will be an attempt-less emotion as an engineer.

Also, Study the common mistakes/problems where the design patterns should be applied most likely; then (without re-inventing) the wheel, you might be able to make correct technical decisions upfront with correct design patterns where applicable.

One practice I used to embrace as a Sofware Engineer was D3 (Design Driven Development); where any of the effective coding is not started (yeah, not a word!!) until the full or JEDUF (Just-Enough-Design-Up-Front) is completely done; which means, just before the "effective" coding to be started you "exactly" know how to define your workflows and wiring them via applicable patterns, etc. (Additionally, this approach will reduce the code-reviewing time a lot)

So I'd say, the catch is, how much of patterns you have covered in terms of their conceptual spirit and how much skills you got to make the correct judgement to choose the correct pattern when the correct time/place comes.

Cheers, D

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in good software design read about:  [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)  or [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), or  [Test Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) . Design patterns described by GoF doesn't refer to big picture software design, rather how to solve common problems withing certain context.

Bear in mind that software design is not something written in stone, all depends on context. Main goal is to deliver requested (correct) features to the user, make code testable, maintainable and within certain constraints like time and budget.

In agile environment, usually no one is making whole design with every detail in it, but the architecture of the software emerges during agile process. So familiarise yourself with agile methodologies like Scrum, Kanban, Extreme Programming as well.